# Populate NixOS VM wiith files

Tags: nix, nixos

I work with NixOS VMs, I can add packages and services, but I struggle to add files (here some configuration and certificates, `/etc`, and a directory in a user).

I have tried the following:

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:

let
  srcs-etc =
    pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation
      {
        name = "src-etc";
        src = ./.;
        buildInputs = [ ];
        unpackPhase = "true";
        buildPhase = ''
          mkdir -p "$out/etc/nixos"
          cp "$src/configuration.nix" "$out/etc/nixos"
          cp "$src/nix-serve.pem" "$out/etc/nixos"
          cp "$src/nix-serve.pub" "$out/etc/nixos"
        '';
      };
  srcs-project =
    pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation
      {
        name = "src-project";
        src = ./project;
        buildInputs = [ ];
        unpackPhase = "true";
        buildPhase = ''
          mkdir -p "$out/project"
          cp -r "$src" "$out/project"
        '';
      };
in
{
  imports = [ ];

  # Use the systemd-boot EFI boot loader.
  boot.loader.systemd-boot.enable = true;
  boot.loader.efi.canTouchEfiVariables = true;
  networking = {
    hostName = "ci";
  };
  users.users.runner = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    extraGroups = [ ];
    packages = [ srcs-project ];
  };

  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [ srcs-etc ];
  system.stateVersion = "23.11"; # Did you read the comment?
}
```

However all the here-above directories are still empty.

Comment: For the most part `/etc` gets populated during system activation, not during VM build. And packages you install populate `/run/current-system/sw/*`, not `/*`, so if a package installs `/etc/foo` it'll end up is `/run/current-system/sw/etc/foo` if you install it with `system-packages`

Comment: ...there's a cross-site duplicate on [unix.se] (which I'd argue is where this question should be too, being more focused on system administration than Nix-the-programming-language) at [How to add a file to `/etc` in NixOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500025/how-to-add-a-file-to-etc-in-nixos) with an on-point answer.

Comment: BTW, using a package to install `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` is... very weird. Might I suggest structuring your code as a flake? Install a system from a flake and you don't need a `/etc/nixos` to even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to add files to `etc`, you just need to set the `environment.etc` options inside the `config` section of a NixOS module.  See:

- [Documentation for the environment.etc option](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=23.05&show=environment.etc&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=environment.etc)
- [Related question - How to add a file to /etc in NixOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500025/how-to-add-a-file-to-etc-in-nixos)